# Do-loop with ParametricNDSolveValue not giving expected results

Tags: differential-equations, procedural-programming, broken-code

I have written code that using a Do-loop. In the loop I am changing the value of `x, v, l` and `R`, and looking at the computed value of `tot`, which should equal `Z`.  It does not matter what is the values of `x, v, l` or `R` are, `tot` should equal `Z`. However, the loop gives me a different value of `tot`. Can anyone help, please?

```
l1 = 0.81
Z = 500; 
x0 = 10; 
v0 = 0.02; 
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon;
l0 = 0.0714`20.;

ps = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == -4 π l k Exp[-y[r]], 
     y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z l]}, 
    {y, y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, {k}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30];

Do[  
  x = i x0;
  v = i^3 v0; 
  R = Rationalize[v^(-1/3), 0];
  l = Rationalize[l1/(i x0), 0];
  nn = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -10, 0}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]];
  tot = 4 π nn NIntegrate[r^2  Exp[-First[ps[nn]][r]], {r, 0, R}];
  Print[NumberForm[i, 5], "  ", NumberForm[tot, 10]];,
  {i, 2.92, 3.1, 0.01}]
```

Comment: How do we know that `Tot = Z`? This is not visible from your code. Publish the original model so that we can determine where you are wrong.

Comment: because this 4 \[Pi] nn NIntegrate[r^2  Exp[-First[ps[nn]][r]], {r, 0, R}] is Z

Comment: The code contains errors as reported by the system, for example `ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At r == 0.0118143212039451589607246202688186689259764002385033048655`30., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

Comment: you are right. How to fix it?

Comment: The question is, what do you want to fix? We do not know what problem you solve.

Comment: The problem is this integral 4 [Pi] nn NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[ps[nn]][r]], {r, 0, R}]  suppose to give me the number of Z that I assign it in the above of my code, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the code so that in this problem all values should be calculated with a given accuracy. There is an overflow in intermediate calculations, but it apparently does not affect the final result.

```
l1 = 0.81;
Z = 500;
x0 = 10;
v0 = 0.02;
\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon;

l0 = 0.0714`20.;

ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 
      2 y'[r]/r == -4 \[Pi] l k Exp[-y[r]], y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, 
    y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z l]}, {y,
     y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {k, l}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Do[x = i x0;
  v = i^3 v0;
  R = Rationalize[v^(-1/3), 0];
  l = Rationalize[l1/(i x0), 0];
  nn = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0, l]][R], {y0, -1}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 
    2]];
  Tot = 4 \[Pi] nn NIntegrate[
     r^2 Exp[-First[ps[nn, l]][r]], {r, \[Epsilon], R}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 4];
  Print[NumberForm[i*1., 5], "  ", NumberForm[Tot, 5]];, {i, 292/100, 
   31/10, 1/100}] // Quiet
```

2.92  500.05

2.93  500.05

2.94  500.05

2.95  500.05

2.96  500.05

2.97  500.06

2.98  500.06

2.99  500.06

3. 500.06

3.01  500.06

3.02  500.06

3.03  500.06

3.04  500.06

3.05  500.06

3.06  500.06

3.07  500.06

3.08  500.06

3.09  500.05

3.1  500.05

Comment: Thank you so much.