# Need help solving ODE with ParametricNDSolveValue solver

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, function-construction, parametric-functions

I am trying to apply [@bbgodfrey method for finding the right initial guess](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210706/help-in-finding-a-good-guesses-for-ode)  for the following problem 
 but I get an error message and I don't understand where it comes from.

I would also like to know why FindRoot in `Do loop` doesn't work in this case.

Below is my minimal working code:

```
l1 = 0.81;
Z = 500;
x0 = 10;
v0 = 0.02;
\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon;
yl = -12;
yu = 0;

l0 = 0.0714`20.;

ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 
      2 y'[r]/r == -4 \[Pi] l k Exp[-y[r]], y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, 
    y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z l]}, {y,
     y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {k, l}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Do[x = i x0;
  v = i^3 v0;
  yl = -12;
  yu = 0;
  R = Rationalize[v^(-1/3), 0];
  l = Rationalize[l1/(i x0), 0];
  fy := (Do[yc = (yl + yu)/2;  (* guess finder function *)

     test = First[ps[yc]]["Domain"][[1, 2]];
     If[test == 1, Throw[yc]];
     If[Last[ps[yc]][test] > 0, yu = yc, yl = yc], {i, 50}]; yc);
  yint = 
   Which[1 == First[ps[yl]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yl, 
    1 == First[ps[yu]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yu, True, Catch[fy]];
  nn = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, yint}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 
     2]];
  Tot = 4 \[Pi] nn NIntegrate[
     r^2 Exp[-First[ps[nn, l]][r]], {r, \[Epsilon], R}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 4];
  Print[NumberForm[i*1., 5], "  ", NumberForm[Tot, 5]];, {i, 292/100, 
   31/10, 1/100}]
```

Comment: The first error message your code gives me says that `ps` was called with one parameter having a value of -12. That would be in the line ψint = ...  ps[ yl ] ... Your definition of ps expects 2 parameters. However, the definition of ps contains y0 and R, which are undefined. Perhaps y0 and R should be a third and fourth parameters of `ps` ? If they are not parameters, they need numeric values. Also, to debug loops, start with `With[ {i=3}, ... ]` and add statements one at a time, making sure each one works for the value of `i`. Then try to replace the `With` with `Table` instead of `Do`.

Comment: @LouisB First, I need to work with `Do`. And in `Do` statements  `R` is numerical value. For `y0`, I belived that the code should take   `yint` and pass it to `y0`. Also, there is a typo ψint  should be yint.

Comment: Just to understand the syntax, try this immediately after your `ps = ` statement, `y0 = 1; R = 1.2;
Plot[ ps[0.5, 0.027] [[1]] [r], {r, 0, R},
 PlotRange -> {{0, R}, {0, 4}}]`.  This indicates we must set values of y0 and R, then evaluate `ps` with 2 parameters, followed by a subscript of 1 or 2 followed by `[ r ]`.  Of course we could use `First` and `Last` instead of the `[[ ... ]]` notation.

Comment: @LouisB OK. I just want to let know that the code that I am using is taken from here [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183148/do-loop-with-parametricndsolvevalue-not-giving-expected-results], and it works fine. What I am asking here is to implemented bbgodfrey method for finding the right initial guess to the above code.

Comment: @aluuzz 1) what problem do you want to solve? 2) it looks so that you have syntax errors there.

Comment: @AlexTrounev the ode is very stiff for high value of `Z` or `l` and I do not need for each value to put the initial guess from my head and so on.., I want to use the method mentioned above to find the initial guess for any value of Z or l. like `Z = 20000` or higher. So, how to insert the method  in my `do loop code`?

Comment: @aluuzz There are typos in `Do[]`. Therefore, it is not clear what you want to calculate there. Can you give one working code without `Do[]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev WELL there are  typos in `Do[]` and that what I need to resolve it, basically can you get the solution for this problem for higher value of `Z` and `l` see the link.  [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183148/do-loop-with-parametricndsolvevalue-not-giving-expected-results]]

Comment: @AlexTrounev What is your initial guess fro `{y0, -10, 0}`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I need a way to find a good initial guess for `Z[0 to 20000]' . An iteration way that's it.

Comment: @AlexTrounev your answer is wrong because `Tot` has to be equal to `Z`? also I am asking for finding an iteration method for finding the initial guess!

Comment: well this `Tot = 4 \[Pi] nn NIntegrate[
     r^2 Exp[-First[ps[nn, l]][r]], {r, \[Epsilon], R}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 4]` has to equal `Z` for checking.

Comment: @aluuzz Can we move the discussion to my answer?  There are already too many comments.

Comment: Sorry we can not.

Comment: @aluuzz I found that my code worked well up to `Z=15000`. I also found the parameter area where code bbgodfrey works. See update.

Comment: Well. There is different between 15000  and 15007!! And, you did not answer my question.

Comment: @aluuzz 15000 and 15007 are a consequence of the numerical method used, which cannot give an accurate result. We can increase the accuracy, but then the time will increase. Code at bbgodfrey gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

We can use my [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183148/do-loop-with-parametricndsolvevalue-not-giving-expected-results]]) without changing for `Z<=15000`

```
l1 = 0.81;
Z = 15000;
x0 = 10;
v0 = 0.02;
\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon;

l0 = 0.0714`20.;

ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 
      2 y'[r]/r == -4 \[Pi] l k Exp[-y[r]], y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, 
    y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z l]}, {y,
     y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {k, l}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Do[x = i x0;
  v = i^3 v0;
  R = Rationalize[v^(-1/3), 0];
  l = Rationalize[l1/(i x0), 0];
  nn = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0, l]][R], {y0, -1}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 
    2]];
  Tot = 4 \[Pi] nn NIntegrate[
     r^2 Exp[-First[ps[nn, l]][r]], {r, \[Epsilon], R}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 4];
  Print[NumberForm[i*1., 5], "  ", NumberForm[Tot, 5]];, {i, 292/100, 
   31/10, 1/100}] // Quiet
```

Out:

```
2.92  15007.

2.93  15007.

2.94  15006.

2.95  15006.

2.96  15006.

2.97  15006.

2.98  15006.

2.99  15006.

3.  15006.

3.01  15006.

3.02  15006.

3.03  15006.

3.04  15006.

3.05  15006.

3.06  15006.

3.07  15006.

3.08  15005.

3.09  15005.

3.1  15005.
```

I checked code @bbgodfrey (question as it is). The result was much worse than with my code, but the code works for some `k` up to `Z = 20000`:

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := 
 Block[{Z = Z0, g = Rationalize[g0, 0], k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0], 
   yl = -8, yu = 0, ps, fy, y00, sol}, \[Epsilon] = 
   10^-4; R = Rationalize[R0, 0]; 
  ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 
       2 y'[r]/r == -4 Pi k2 Exp[-y[r]], y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, 
     y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, 
     y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  fy := (Do[yc = (yl + yu)/2;
     tst = First[ps[yc]]["Domain"][[1, 2]];
     If[tst == R, Throw[yc]];
     If[Last[ps[yc]][tst] > 0, yu = yc, yl = yc], {i, 50}]; yc);
  y00 = Which[R == First[ps[yl]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yl, 
    R == First[ps[yu]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yu, True, Catch[fy]];
  sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, y00}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 
    2]]; L = 
   4 \[Pi] k2/g0 NIntegrate[
     r^2 Exp[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, \[Epsilon], R}]]
```

Using of `p[]`

```
l1 = 0.81;
Z0 = 20000;
x0 = 10;
v0 = 0.02;
l0 = 0.0714`20.; k = 1/29;
 Do[x = i x0;
 v = i^3 v0;
 R = Rationalize[v^(-1/3), 0];
 l = Rationalize[l1/(i x0), 0];
 Print[NumberForm[i*1., 5], "  ", 
  NumberForm[p[Z0, l, k l, R] // Quiet, 5]];, {i, 292/100, 31/10, 
  1/100}]
```

Out

```
2.92  20010.

2.93  20010.

2.94  20010.

2.95  20009.

2.96  20009.

2.97  20009.

2.98  20009.

2.99  20008.

3.  20008.

3.01  8.3397*10^(21)

3.02  1.309*10^(22)

3.03  2.0575*10^(22)

3.04  3.2386*10^(22)

3.05  5.1048*10^(22)

3.06  8.0576*10^(22)

3.07  1.2736*10^(23)

3.08  2.0159*10^(23)

3.09  3.1952*10^(23)

3.1  5.0714*10^(23)
```